# grunt-contrib-cssmin removes box-sizing property

Tags: css, gruntjs, minify, grunt-contrib-cssmin

My stylesheets work fine until I use grunt-contrib-cssmin to minify my stylesheets.

This part:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

is completely gone after minifying.

I've tried escaping the asterisk:

```
\*, \*::before, \*::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

It worked in Chrome but was not showing in Firefox.

Is there any workaround or fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Added *`\*`* infront of *`*, *::before, *::after`*.

**Code:**

```
\*, *, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```